# Get the directory path of a running process ID

Tags: path, directory, freebsd

How can I get a full path to the directory of a running process (I know the process ID & name).

I was using `ls -l /proc/PID/cwd` earlier in Debian, but it doesn't work in FreeBSD.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, found the answer: `procinfo -b PIDID`.